# LISP Function that Returns True If Atom Is In List

Tags: list, recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to write a function (deep-find) that takes in a list and another argument and returns T if that argument is present in the list. For example, if I called `(deep-find '(A B (C D)) 'C)` it should return true, but if I called `(deep-find '(A B (C D)) 'F)` it should return false. Here's the code I have so far, but it returns nil every time:

```
(defun deep-find (L n)
  (cond
   ((null L) nil)
   ((equal n (car L)) t)
   ((deep-find (cdr L) n))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code does not return `NIL` *every time*; it works well for simple lists. For instance `(deep-find '(A B (C D)) 'A)` returns `T` as it should.

You have three cases in your `cond`: end of list, list head check, and list tail check. However, there is nothing regarding *trees* in that. So, you need another condition that recurses into the deeper levels of a tree in case of a branch in the tree:

```
(defun deep-find (L n)
  (cond
   ((null L) nil)
   ((equal n (car L)) t)
   ((listp (car L))             ; in case of a branch,
    (or (deep-find (car L) n)   ; check the branch,
        (deep-find (cdr L) n))) ; and check rest of the list
   ((deep-find (cdr L) n))))
```

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

What you are calling a list is in fact binary tree. In Common Lisp list is defined as head and tail, while tree consists of car and cdr, which are node's children. Note, that list is a special case of tree.

Common Lisp provides a few functions responsible for traversing trees:

- #'subst
- #'subst-if
- #'equal-tree

which are equivalents for functions working on lists:

- #'substitute
- #'substitute-if
- #'equal

Here: http://lisptips.com/post/43404489000/the-tree-walkers-of-cl you may find original tip. According to that, following code may solve your problem:

```
(defun deep-find (lst elt)
  (prog1 nil
    (subst-if t (constantly nil) lst
              :key (lambda (x)
                     (when (eql elt x)
                       (return-from deep-find t))))))
```

Comment: #'subst-if may be replaced with #'tree-equal, but using former, we may replace #'eql with #'equal, and match list.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes this kind of problem becomes easier if you add more flexibility.

For example considering generic binary trees instead of just lists (that are a specific sub-case of binary trees) and also assuming that the correct answer for `(deep-find 'a 'a)` should be `T` the code becomes shorter and more elegant:

```
(defun deep-find (tree item)
  (or (equal tree item)
      (and (consp tree)
           (or (deep-find (car tree) item)
               (deep-find (cdr tree) item)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

One more way,

```
(defun deep-see (lis arg)
 (let ((result))
  (cond
   ((not (null lis))
    (loop for item in lis do
     (cond
      ((not (equal item arg))
       (cond ((listp item) (setf result (deep-see item arg)))))
      ((equal item arg) (setf result t))))))
  result))
```

Usage:`(deep-see '(a v c (e (c (((d)))) f)) 'd)` => T

`(deep-see '(a v c (e (c (((d e)))) f)) '(d e))` => T

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
(defun deep-find (expr list)
(cond 
    ((equal list expr) t)
    ((not (atom list)) 
        (or 
            (deep-find expr (car list))
            (deep-find expr (cdr list))
        )
    )
)
```